Why Django Signals async post-save is locking other async ORM calls?
I have a Django 5 application that use websockets using channels, and I'm trying to switch to AsyncConsumers to take advantage of asyncronous execution for I/O or external API tasks.
I already wrote a demo project and everything it's working fine, however in my application I use Django signals, and I have a long I/O task to be performed in the post_save of MyModel, previously implemented using threads:
from asyncio import sleep

@receiver(dj_models.signals.post_save, sender=MyModel)
async def auto_process_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  logger.log("Starting Long Save task");
  await sleep(30)
  logger.log("Starting Long Save task");

The websocket consumer that is serving the request is similar to the following:
from channels.generic import websocket

class AsyncGenericConsumer(websocket.AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

   async def connect(self):
      await self.accept()
   
   ...
   
   async def receive_json(self, message):
      ...
      user = await User.objects.aget(id=...)
      # Authentication code
      # ....
      # (eventually) Create MyModel, depending on request type
      mod = await my_models.MyModel.objects.acreate(...)

Now, the problem is as follow:
When Alice's request is still performing a post_save operation (i.e., awaiting the long task contained in it) and a Bob user opens up the browser and makes a request to the same consumer, the computation gets stuck to user = await User.objects.aget(id=...) until the long task (e.g., the asyncio.sleep(30)) terminates for Alice.
The actual application is much more complex than this and we can't get rid of the post_save.
I would like to understand how the .aget() on a model could get locked by a post_save on another model, when they should be asynchronous calls and be processed as such.
Are there ways to avoid this while still using asyncio code?
I am using the latest versions of all the packages involved.
Thanks for your support.

First thing I'd look there is if "long_save" really calls asynchronous code, and awaits properly on it - if for some reason, it is CPU bound, or have synchronous long tasks, the effects would be as you describe.

Yes, I both checked into the django code and run a debug session, the signal is called asynchronously as advertised...

What's the long task doing? Might be a database level lock. What DB are you using?

@EDG956 The long task is simply a call to an external API, but the problem persists also when I substitute that call with an await asyncio.sleep(). The database is postgres.
